# C++ Connector to MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

EDITED:

My Problem is the errors at the bottom of this post.

Heres my additional include directories

```
C:\Program Files\boost
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.3\include
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include
```

Additional Library Directories

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 1.1.2\lib\opt
```

Additional Dependencies

```
libmysql.lib
mysqlcppconn-static.lib
```

Heres my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#define host "localhost"
#define username "root"
#define password "root"
#define database "tests"

int main()
{
    MYSQL* conn;
    conn = mysql_init( NULL );
    if( conn )
    {
        mysql_real_connect( conn, host, username, password, database, 0, NULL, 0 );
    }
    MYSQL_RES* res_set;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    unsigned int i;
    mysql_query( conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_clients WHERE id = 1" ); 
    res_set = mysql_store_result( conn );
    unsigned int numrows = mysql_num_rows( res_set ); 
    if( numrows )
    {
        row = mysql_fetch_row( res_set );
        if( row != NULL )
        {
            cout << "Client ID  : " << row[0] << endl;
            cout << "Client Name: " << row[1] << endl;
        }
    }
    if( res_set )
    {
        mysql_free_result( res_set );
    }
    if( conn )
    {
        mysql_close( conn );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

These are the errors I get

```
1>------ Build started: Project: okay, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>welp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_num_rows@4 referenced in function _main
1>welp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_init@4 referenced in function _main
1>welp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_connect@32 referenced in function _main
1>welp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_query@8 referenced in function _main
1>welp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_store_result@4 referenced in function _main
1>welp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_free_result@4 referenced in function _main
1>welp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_fetch_row@4 referenced in function _main
1>welp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_close@4 referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\Damian\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\okay\Debug\okay.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Please help, This project is due in about 48 hours for my class, and I've spent so much time trying to figure this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

respectfully, your last two questions are compiler/linker questions. I understand your frustration, as I knew how to code early but knew nothing about compilers/linkers. When you get a moment take some time to read about:

- headers
- binary vs object file
- libraries / shared object
- compiler
- linker
- function mangling (C vs C++)

To answer your question, I am guessing you're doing this in Microsoft Visual Studio:

1. You need to go to Project Properties and set Additional Library Paths (i see you did that from your last post)
2. You need to specify the library, I'm going out on a limb here and assuming it will `mysql.lib` ... There's an "Additional Library" input somewhere in the Linker section, you'll be able to identify it because `kernel32.lib` will be int it. Add the `mysql.lib` to that section. Confirm the name by going to the mysql folder which holds the binaries.
3. Make sure you're using the static library, the `.dll` will give you new issues that you don't need to worry about. This is usually achieved by setting the correct library directory. Many c++ libraries will ship with precompiled "Static" and "Dynamic" folders containing the correct libraries.

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast response, just edited my above post, and saw your reply. I'll keep working at it

Comment: Well, still to no avail so far. There is no mysql.lib in any folder i have. I know that when you said that you were just taking a guess, but if i had to guess which one it was, i'd guess it would have to be libmysql.lib. And i have included that and still nothing. I've been reading through about all these kind of things and i'm still stuck.

Comment: You are correct with `libmysql.lib`. Perhaps there are other libraries? As Shan noted this a linker problem and thus not your code but your CONFIGURATION. Make sure you really are getting the same errors btw, you might be getting new errors for OTHER symbols.

Comment: Fixed my problem, I guess i'd been using 64 bit mysql with a 32bit program or so, but now im getting different errors, but am trying to find a fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is error is happening due to linker problem. The **linker is not able to find the required static or dynamic libraries** (**mysql.lib,mysqlcppconn-static.lib,libmysql.dll and libmysql.lib**). The **additional lib setting is wrong**. Check this site give the path correctly [Building MySQL Connector/C++ Windows Applications with Microsoft Visual Studio](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong with this. I see that it must be a probably with my additional dependencies, cause i have these 8 errors BEFORE even put libmysql.dll and mysqlcppconn-static.lib into the additional dependencies. When I add them into the dependencies nothing changes. I know that the linker can find the files too because of some tinkering with it, when I found that my older error was that i didn't include the library directory. But now I did, but these errors are still coming up