# Is MySQL a good option for working with C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql-server, eclipse, mysql-connector

I am trying to work on a project that involves the use of databases.

I have the codes done in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) to work with simple data structure (CSV format). But now I want to use a larger set of data.

I have tried to connect the [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) to [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) in Eclipse by `C++ Connector`, but it needs a lot of modification (adding library path, installing cmake, ...).

Until now I couldn't figure out what is the problem with a simple code of MySQL downloaded from internet. The code seems very complex, so I am not sure I am choosing a good option to deal with a large data set.

Is worth it to move to [python](/questions/tagged/python) (very easy instructions and they are every where) or [java](/questions/tagged/java) ? 
Is switching to another database management system is gonna help me with this or is there a way to get a hold of MySQL? (I'm very new to MySQL)

Comment: How large is your "large" data structure?

Comment: It is around 1 Gigabyte of a CSV file

Comment: And exactly what are you doing with the data? If you are only loading it up and processing it, it's probably quicker/more efficient to load it up in a program. But if you are running many queries against the same data, it's worth doing a MySQL integration. However, don't expect that to be just a couple of lines of code. I've only ever used MySQL with PHP, which isn't that difficult, but I believe "Connector" is your best choice if you want C++.

Comment: It is a customer purchase database. I want to extract the history of each customer and save it somewhere and then do some calculations between eat of the customer history's. I tried to use the C++ connector (from MySQL webpage), but since my coding is in Eclipse and the compiler is MinGW, I couldn't find necessary help to even get it started. I thought it could be a very complex task to do since nobody is doing it.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you on the details, but I'm 99.9% sure that you can get Eclipse to do what you need. It's pretty flexible, and I'd be extremely surprised if Connector doesn't work with MingW, since you can compile MySQL itself with gcc.

Comment: If you're new to mySQL, maybe setting it up is the problem. Can you access your database from the command line? Sqlite might be easier to install. I have no experience with the Eclipse Connector, I prefer to use an ODBC interface, but Eclipse connector looks rather similar and not much complicated. Have you tried one of the examples?

Comment: @Zane I couldn't get the Eclipse connect to MySQL. I tried to run an example by different ways that are suggested on the web to connect to MySQL, but there are always different errors showing up. I have tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455350/c-connector-to-mysql and http://www.nitecon.com/tutorials-articles/develop/cpp/c-mysql-beginner-tutorial/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/51320/, but non of them are working for me.

Comment: I propose you start with sqlite. First you'll need to install sqlite - that will depend on your OS and platfrom. one way to learn about sqlite is this tutorial: http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/. Once you see that your data tables work in sqlite, try to do the same from C++. There are many ways to connect to sqlite - one example is here http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html.